# How do I convert dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss to dd-mm-yy hh:mm in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I have dataframe with timestamp as character type in the format `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm`,
for example:

```
"05-02-2018 06:30"
```

I need output in the format of `mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm`, i.e.:

```
"02-05-2018 06.30"
```

I tried lubridate library with function mdy() and also as.POSIXct
but its not working for all of the records -
for few its throwing warning message `"failed to parse."` and
it is mostly for dates where ***day is > 12***, for example:

```
"19-06-2017 16:30"
"22-10-2017 11:45"
"14-09-2017 16:00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `?strptime()` to display help. In the help file there is a list of format properties which you have to specify when using `strptime()`:

[strptime() help](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html)

The most important for your problem are:

%d
Day of the month as decimal number (01–31).

%H
Hours as decimal number (00–23). As a special exception strings such as 24:00:00 are accepted for input, since ISO 8601 allows these.

%m
Month as decimal number (01–12).

%M
Minute as decimal number (00–59).

%Y
Year with century. Note that whereas there was no zero in the original Gregorian calendar, ISO 8601:2004 defines it to be valid (interpreted as 1BC): see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(year). Note that the standards also say that years before 1582 in its calendar should only be used with agreement of the parties involved.

Part of the string is a Seperator as well. In your case "-".

Then you can exchange the month and day using strptime() and format(). Using your example:

```
dates <- c( "19-06-2017 16:30" ,"22-10-2017 11:45", "14-09-2017 16:00")
dates <- strptime(dates, format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
dates_changed <- format(dates, "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M")
```

Answer (score 1):

Lubridate's `dmy_hms` function works.

**Method 1:**

```
library(lubridate)
dts <- c("19-06-2017 16:30" ,"22-10-2017 11:45", "14-09-2017 16:00")
dts <- dmy_hms(dts)
print(dts)

[1] "19-06-2017 16:30" "22-10-2017 11:45" "14-09-2017 16:00"
```

**Method 2:**

```
library(lubridate)
dts <- c("19-06-2017 16:30" ,"22-10-2017 11:45", "14-09-2017 16:00")
dts <- fast_strptime(dts, format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
print(dts)

[1] "2017-06-19 16:30:00 UTC" "2017-10-22 11:45:00 UTC" "2017-09-14 16:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: > library(lubridate)
> dts <- c("19-06-2017 16:30" ,"22-10-2017 11:45", "14-09-2017 16:00")
> dts <- dmy_hms(dts)
> dts
[1] "2020-06-19 17:16:30 UTC" "2020-10-22 17:11:45 UTC" "2020-09-14 17:16:00 UTC"
> dts <- mdy_hms(dts)
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
Unfortunately even dmy_hms(dts) thrwoing me weird results

Comment: This is weird because I am not getting any such error. Anyways, I've added method 2 which should work. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

check for help of `strptime()` function to better format your time/date.

There are multiple approaches you can use here.

Refer to cheetsheet of `lubridate` package within this link: [Lubridate](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/)

Comment: I believe `strptime()` is from base R, not `lubridate`